# Terraform conditions for Output

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

Subnet names will vary based on env being non prod or prod.
Can't use both count and for_each based refer error below.

Need either of two things :
Either execute resource block only if env is prod?
Or output.tf to ignore error if value is not found from resource.

```
 resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
     count               = var.environment == "prd" ? 1 : 0 //execute block only if env is prod
      for_each             = var.subnet_names
      name                 = join("",["test-","${var.environment}",each.key,"-snet"])
      resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.resource_group_name
      virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
      address_prefixes     = tolist(each.value) 
      }
```

Variables.tf

```
variable "subnet_names" {
  description = "subnet names"
  default = {}
  type        = map

}

variable "environment" {
  description = "Name of prod environment"
  default     = "prd"
}
```

tfvars :

```
subnet_names = {
   "s1-uat" = ["20.0.0.0/27"] ,
   "s1-qa" = ["20.0.0.32/27"] ,
  "s2-qa" = ["20.0.0.64/27"] ,
   "s2-uat" = ["20.0.0.96/27"]
}


environment = "prd"
```

output.tf

```
 "s1_subnet_name" {
  value       = azurerm_subnet.subnet["s1-uat"].name
  depends_on = [
azurerm_subnet.subnet
]
}
```

Error :
The "count" and "for_each" meta-arguments are mutually-exclusive, only one
should be used to be explicit about the number of resources to be created.

Comment: You should do something along the lines of `for_each = var.environment == "prd" ? var.subnet_names : {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use only count  or for_each. So you can try this:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
     count               = var.environment == "prd" ? length(var.subnet_names) : 0      
      name                 = join("",["test-","${var.environment}",each.key,"-snet"])
      resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.resource_group_name
      virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
      address_prefixes     = tolist(each.value) 
      }
```

For name and address_prefixes instead of using **'each'** you can use **count.index** . In terraform **count** doesn't support **each**